# ruby commands all directed at .rbenv file

Tags: ruby, rbenv

```
$ gem install bundler
bash: /Users/zhenhaowu/.rbenv/shims/gem: No such file or directory
```

any other commands have been directed to my .rbenv file.

I was trying to downgrade to a older version and tried with rbenv and ruby-build, but it feels like my ruby is screwed up right now .

```
$ which -a ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

could someone help solve this ?

i would love to remove all .rbenv and will not want to work with that again.

Answer (score 0):

so i found out that after installing rbenv, i have to rehash

answers are as stated here.

https://gist.github.com/MicahElliott/2407918

BUT still if i would like to work without rbenv, i'm unaware of how can i remove the path directed at .rbenv